# Flyway doesn't execute in default phase

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, flyway

I'm working on Maven project and I've added flyway plugin which executes sql scripts for testing purposes. I want to be sure that those scripts aren't executed accidently but only with *"mvn ... flyway:migrate"*.

I've found that default phase for *migrate* operation is *pre-integration-test*, but when I run *mvn clean install* flyway isn't invoked (that's ok for me but I want to be know **why** they aren't invoked).

Here is part of *pom.xml*:

```
        <plugin>             
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
            <version>3.0</version>             
            <configuration>
                <driver>${db-driver-name}</driver>
                <url>${db-url}</url>
                <user>${db-user-name}</user>
                <password>${db-user-password}</password>
                <locations>
                    <location>filesystem:./src/main/resources/db/scripts/V${db-version}</location>
                </locations>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>schema</schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    <version>11.2.0.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set `flyway.skip` to `true` by default and only make it false when you want to run the migrations.

Also,  pre-integration-test comes after package. So that's why it isn't invoked with mvn clean package.

Comment: Yeah, I edited question, I was thinking on *mvn clean install*.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you have your `<plugin>` section on its own in the module you want it to run on.

And not only within a `<pluginManagement>` section.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin may contain multiple goals, as in this case you have not only migrate but also clean, info etc. Unless you define in the executions of you project, which of the goals you want to run, they won't run.

You have to specify the goal in the executions block of the plugin xml definition as this:

```
  <plugin>             
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>3.0</version> 
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>migrate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>            
        <configuration>
            <driver>${db-driver-name}</driver>
            <url>${db-url}</url>
            <user>${db-user-name}</user>
            <password>${db-user-password}</password>
            <locations>
                <location>filesystem:./src/main/resources/db/scripts/V${db-version}</location>
            </locations>
            <schemas>
                <schema>schema</schema>
            </schemas>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```